# pg_dump freezes when I run it inside a docker container based on python image

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, dockerfile, pg-dump

I have an application in a container based on a custom dockerfile, that runs a Python code in a schedule, but I wanted to add a feature to back up a postgres database inside my Python pipeline code. But when I try to run pg_dump, it freezes.

I have an example dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11.2-slim
ENV PGPASSWORD "mypgpassword"

RUN apt update
RUN apt install postgresql-client -y

CMD pg_dump --host "subdomain.host.com" --port "5432" --username "myusername" -d "mydatabasename" --verbose > test.sql
```

But it doesn't work, the pg_dump freezes and does nothing. There only appears an empty file test.sql, so I tested a bit more...

After trying it with python:3.11.2-slim, I tested it with python:3.11, and the results were the same.

Then I tested on a virtual machine I have with Ubuntu, and it worked perfectly, then I try using an image not from Python but from ubuntu:latest, and it worked just fine.

Which is unexpected, I thought that the Python image could do the same.

Comment: Try using -f instead of redirecting pipe output and see if it helps

Comment: I also tried it with:
pg_dump --host "subdomain.host.com" --port "5432" --username "myusername" -d "mydatabasename" --verbose --file=test.sql

But didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `python:3.11.2` image (not the slim version), which comes with more preinstalled packages and is based on a full-fledged Debian distribution.

I think it will solve your issue as well.

Comment: I thought the same and already tried it with python:3.11 but it didn't work